# C# Add New System.IO To Visual Express 2010

Tags: c#

Really simple question up for grabs.

I'm using Visual Studio Express 2010 and want to use System.IO.FileInfo

How do I add it in so that it is usable in classes?

Thanks.

Comment: Don't really understand your question, System.IO is part of framework BCL, its easily usable in all classes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add this to using directives at top of file:

```
using System.IO;
```

Then simply use like so:

```
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(filepath);
```

Answer (score 2):

[`FileInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx) is defined in `mscorlib` which will be referenced in any .NET project (it also contains `object`; you can't do without it), so you don't really need to do anything special. Just add `using System.IO;` to the top of your code file and `FileInfo` should be easily available for you.